# Working with In-Browser Editing in Muse

Tags: adobe, muse

to Work with "In-Browser Editing" in Muse should the site be hosted on muse? or can i do this on my host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site should be UPLOADED THROUGH muse (not: hosted on muse) so that every time that a change is made muse will sync the website. You can use whatever hosting service you want and to make changes you either:

go on

[inbrowserediting.com](http://inbrowserediting.com)

or

you re-upload the site from muse.

Here there is a video that might clear things up:

[Video](https://helpx.adobe.com/muse/how-to/muse-in-browser-site-editing.html)

Answer (score 0):

It won't work through 3rd party ftp. You have to FTP through muse or it won't sync.